# String comparison in Mybatis SQL Fails

Tags: sql, jdbc, mybatis

There are two cases, one of which passes while other fails.

Case 1: Fails or Returns 0 for all #{password} values

```
SELECT @out = CASE WHEN (SELECT CONVERT( VARCHAR(MAX), DECRYPTBYKEY(hashed_key)) AS someKey FROM t_key_table WHERE is_active = 1) = '#{password}'
                    THEN 1 
                    ELSE 0 
                  END
```

Case 2: Passes on correct ${password} value and returns 0 for others

```
SELECT @out = CASE WHEN (SELECT CONVERT( VARCHAR(MAX), DECRYPTBYKEY(hashed_key)) AS someKey FROM t_key_table WHERE is_active = 1) = '${password}'
                        THEN 1 
                        ELSE 0 
                      END
```

Currently my reasoning is that #{} returns PreparedStatement which might hinder with the comparison process, but i am unable to find any specific doc or something concrete to help me understand this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please see the [FAQ](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/wiki/FAQ#what-is-the-difference-between--and-).

Comment: This doesn't completely explains na

Comment: MyBatis replaces `#{}` with `?` which is a placeholder in [`java.sql.PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html). If you, however, enclose it in a single quotes, it becomes a string literal `'?'` and the driver cannot bind the parameter value to it. Just remove the single quotes `... = #{password}` and it should work.